# Django rest api: how to return a JsonArray of jsonObjects as a model field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two django models as shown

model 1

```
class Big(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

model2

```
class Small(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    big = models.ForeignKey(Big, related_name='small',null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

There can be more than one Small items inside a Big item. The Bigserializer looks like below

```
class BigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Hotel
    fields = ('name','small')
```

Now on accessing the Big items,i am getting name and small fields. But the small field returns only the id of the Small model. I need the whole details like name and address of Small item inside the small field. How could i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define Small serializer class:

```
class SmallSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Small
        fields = ('name','address')
```

and use this serializer in `BigSerializer` class:

```
class BigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    small = SmallSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields = ('name','small')
```

See details [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

Note that if you need writable nested serialization, you should implement custom `create` and `update` methods inside `BigSerializer`, see section [writable nested serialization](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).